# amount of attempts Authentication password

Tags: authentication, password-recovery

Is there an amount of attempts when I forget the authentication password?
Like Iphone or something when after 3 times the phone is locked for 30 sec, and after that for 5 minutes (and so on..)?

I have some optional passwords to try but I don't want to disable the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will not be locked out if you have started a certain number of incorrect attempts. At least not in the default installation.

But it is possible, via PAM. **;)**